# SSIS: Input columns not returning for Mysql ODBC connector

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am having a problem with a SSIS project that downloads data from a MySQL database and insert it in a SQL Server Database. I added the ODBC connector and can preview the data but can't return the input columns. I used SQL command too where I could preview the data but input columns doesn't show up

[image]

Comment: Does the preview button show the output in the connection manager?

Comment: @MostafaNZ yes, the preview shows the data

Comment: Try ADO.NET. set the "data access mode" to sql command.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up using a custom script component.
Reading the data into a DataTable provides the ability to read the columns and their type.

Something like this:

```
DataTable sqlDataTable = new DataTable();
OdbcDataReader odbcRead;

OdbcCommand odbcCmd = new OdbcCommand("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
odbcRead = odbcCmd.ExecuteReader();
sqlDataTable.Load(odbcRead);
```

Sadly, as of now we were unable to provide a better solution.